# How to make number of samples in two audios with same name equal?

Tags: python, librosa, pydub

I have two audios with same name say `a.wav`
But both the audios having different number of samples, how could i make number of samples same in both the audios?
Any kind of help or hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Your question is unclear, are saying that they are different length but same sampling rate or that they have the same sampling rate but different length, or you want to resample so both are the same sampling rate?

Comment: What samples? Wav is a consistent audio format, it doesn't have separate samples inside it.

Comment: @EdChum yes the audios are of different length, having same sampling rate but having different length hence different number of samples. How to make those two audios of same length.

Comment: @FlashThunder by number of samples i mean to say (audio_length * sampling_rate) i.e. 16000 in my case.